# Weird if() Conditional with Wordpress doing the opposite needs to explain

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Well, while im working in my project I decided to get some help from `if ( is(home) )` in WordPress, i needed to clean the footer/header/boddy in front page of my WordPress(the index only) so I got the Conditional from wp[dot]org/Function_Reference/is_home

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
        get_footer();
}
```

It didn't work and I was able to see the footer in the front index page
although it should work since everything is right for now
so I changed it to be:

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
        get_footer();
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
```

With this change, I wouldn't be able to see it, it worked, perfectly, how is that?

Something goes wrong I guess I will leave it since it worked, but i need to know how it worked, and if it's going to have an effect on the other pages?

PS: I've checked the other pages and YES, I'm able to see the footer area
but I didn't check them all, and I'm afraid that my Client face this problem in the future.

Comment: did you change your template recently? I know I had some problems with certain types of templates

Comment: Try `is_front_page()` rather than `is_home()`.

Comment: With such a small snippet of the code, it is hard to say, but take a look at the docs.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home  They seem to indicate that `is_home isn't usable before the parse_query action`.  You might want to look at where you are calling this.

Comment: Also, check this - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17697/is-home-returns-false-on-the-home-page-when-is-the-home-page-not-the-home-pag

Comment: @.vodich yes, i keeping change it
@buggabil my bad, i didn't read the full article

guys, im only asked for explain xD, take it easier than that, im still newest the newbie in php programming xD, and im here to learn from experts like you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So make you're own few lines of code to do the same.

In index.php before get_header...

`<?php $myvar = 'home';?>`

Then in the header.php

```
<?php if($myvar == 'home') { ?>
some code
<?php } else { ?>
some other code
<?php } ?>
```

Very basic example, but very easy to do...

This assumes you have other template files to handle other pages, such as categories etc...

Still possible if you only use an index file, just requires a little more work...

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel?  Wordpress includes the needed functions, and adding your own will only serve to help create a maintenance nightmare for the next person?

Comment: I had a similar problem just a way I found around it thought I'd share but not the best solution.

Comment: It is nice that he did try to help, but you also need to make sure that, before installing a solution like this in production code, you explore solutions that will be easier for your successors to find and debug.  This includes using the existing functions that the platform provides and not rolling your own.  Just because you can code it on your own doesn't mean that you should.